# How to stop response until page get full load with pdfkit.from_url in python

Tags: python, django, pdfkit

I am converting url to pdf file by using pdfkit.from_url. Here when ever I hit that url then with in fraction to seconds it is converting to pdf(here it is not waiting to load all data in page url). my problem is how to stop pdfkit.from_url until page data get load full. Please give me slolution. This is my code

pdf_file = pdfkit.from_url(url, path + 'assigned_id' + '_' + str(assign_code) + '.pdf', options=options)

Comment: i have used this also.                                                                                                    
  options = { 'javascript-delay':'5000' }

Answer (score 0):

what you should do is add delay when you click on url enough for the page to load

```
import time

time.sleep(5)  #wait for five seconds
pdf_file = pdfkit.from_url(url, path + 'assigned_id' + '_' + str(assign_code) + '.pdf', 
options=options) #your code will run after the delay
```

Comment: After hit that url, response have to wait till 10 seconds.so in that mean time my page will load with data then I can convert to pdf. Please For this how can I do.

Comment: yes just set enough time for your website to load and your code will work fine

Comment: After hit that url, response has to wait till page get lod with data. how can do this.Pls

Comment: create an event that triggers after hitting the url, that event will create the delay for the website data to load

Comment: Thank you for answer, by using python I have to do "response has to wait till url webpage get lod with data", any solution sir

Comment: def usingPDFkit(assigned_id):
 path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'assign_pdf/'
 options = {'page-size': 'A4', 'margin-top': '0.75in', 'margin-right': '0.75in', 'margin-bottom': '0.75in', 'margin-left': '0.75in','javascript-delay':'15000'}
        time.sleep(15) 
 pdf_file = pdfkit.from_url('http://172.25.12.29:9009/onlineexam/pdffun/', path + '.pdf', options=options)

Comment: in pdf file, I am getting only static data, not getting database data.